# Integrating Webflow with Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, webflow

Any suggestions in integrating a Webflow project into a nuxt one? I have been trying to move everything to nuxt but I couldn't figure out a way to use the animations/buton functions from webflow (aka the js file from webflow) or fonts. Thank you!

Note: I have tried the solution from https://discourse.webflow.com/t/vue-js-stops-tabs-interactions/82870 (even though not sure if this is related), but the browser is telling me that Webflow is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I guess there are two approaches how to achieve this based on what you need exactly:

1. If you want to use Webflow for the marketing part of your site and nuxt for some functional pages on the same domain, I would consider setting up a reverse proxy using Cloudflare workers for example. This way you can achieve for instance that mydomain.com shows a Webflow page and mydomain.com/login shows a nuxt page.
2. If you need to mix Webflow with Nuxt on the same page, Webflow’s new DevLink feature could soon be an option for you. At the moment it only supports React though but they‘re adding Vue support soon.